# jQuery functionality lost from some modules after migrating to new host

Tags: javascript

My site was running good until recently. Suddenly none of the modules were able to use jQuery on the site. I came to know about this when I logged in as admin and my Nodequeues were not working.

The button on Panel pages on the top of each region to add content using CTools has also started behaving weirdly. Earlier one had to click on the button on top of each region to see the menu that said *"Add content"* but now that menu is fully expanded without clicking.

Is it correct to conclude that all this is happening because the modules are not able to access the jQuery library? The jQuery UI and jQuery modules are installed and were working properly before yesterday.

Comment: Have you moved your Drupal installation ? Check permission of folder.

Comment: The site was live on pantheon server. They had some trouble with their current server and hence they decided to move all the sites to another server. It all started once they did this migration. So I should say that the drupal installation was moved to new server, but by server people.

Comment: Okay, what is the permission of `misc/ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js` can you access the file through browser ?

Comment: how should I look at it in browser ?

Comment: go to `http://yoursite.com/misc/ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js`

Comment: this url says 'Page not found'

Comment: Do you know whats that mean ?

Comment: HTTP 404 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404, means there is no file exists in that name, if you have FTP access to server please verify that the file exists.

Comment: but if i got to http://yoursite.com/sites/all/modules/jquery_ui/jquery.ui/ui/ui.core.js ,
I am able to view this file.... Does this mean something?

Comment: I am sure thats not the file causing 404, so dont care that. make it work which is not working.

Comment: hey, what if i put this missing file deliberately into the misc/ui folder of my code? Should that make it work?

Comment: Sure it will work. How can you identify all other missing files ?

Comment: That actually is a problem. Finding out other missing files. However can there be another module creating this problem.....I mean there is a jquery plugin handler module. Its configuration page says no configuration exists. I sthere anything to do with this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7870/discussion-between-nikhil-m-and-user1153986)